# Why are my feed cells duplicating?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am using this code to create a feed view that shows users, images, and comments similar to instagram. For some reason, the cells on the feed are duplicating the current user's posts. Not only that, but it is also putting the incorrect username with the images on the duplicate cells. What am I doing wrong?

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class FeedTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var usersBeingFollowed = [String]()
    var imageFiles = [PFFile]()
    var imageComment = [""]
    var usernames = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true


        let getFollowedUsersQuery = PFQuery(className: "Followers")

        getFollowedUsersQuery.whereKey("follower", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)

        getFollowedUsersQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

            self.usernames.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
            self.imageComment.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
            self.imageFiles.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
            self.usersBeingFollowed.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

            if let objects = objects {

                for object in objects {

                    let followedUser = object["following"] as! String

                    let getFollowedUsers = PFQuery(className: "Post")

                    getFollowedUsers.whereKey("userId", equalTo: followedUser)

                    let getCurrentUser = PFQuery(className: "Post")
                    getCurrentUser.whereKey("userId", equalTo: (PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId)!)

                    var query = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([getFollowedUsers,getCurrentUser])

                    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageObjects, error) -> Void in


                        if let objects = imageObjects {

                            for images in objects {

                                let userQuery = PFUser.query()
                                userQuery?.whereKey("_id", equalTo: images["userId"])
                                userQuery?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (user, error) -> Void in
                                    print(user)
                                    if let user = user {
                                        for username in user {
                                            self.usernames.append(username["username"] as! String)
                                        }

                                    }

                                })

                                self.imageFiles.append(images["imageFile"] as! PFFile)
                                self.imageComment.append(images["imageComment"] as! String)
                                self.tableView.reloadData()


                            }

                        }

                    })

                }

            }


        }



    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return usernames.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("imagePostCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! cell

        if imageFiles.count > 0{
            myCell.userLabel.text = "\(usernames[indexPath.row]) completed the \(imageComment[indexPath.row]) challenge!"
            imageFiles[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (data, error) -> Void in
                if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {

                    myCell.imagePost.image = downloadedImage
//                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                }
            })
        }

        return myCell
    }
```

Comment: Cells are reused. After dequeuing a cell you should clear any old content before setting new content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reset the cell property before add new values, you can use

```
prepareForReuse()
```

More info on Apple Doc https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/prepareForReuse

Answer (score 1):

It will be obviously, generate the duplicate content because you have put the condition that `if imageFiles.count > 0` then the data will be displayed.

But what when there are no images? It will definitely take the value from reusable `UITableViewCell`. Check the below change:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("imagePostCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! cell

        if imageFiles.count > 0{
            myCell.userLabel.text = "\(usernames[indexPath.row]) completed the \(imageComment[indexPath.row]) challenge!"
            imageFiles[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (data, error) -> Void in
                if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {

                    myCell.imagePost.image = downloadedImage
//                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                }
            })
        }else{

             myCell.userLabel.text = "Put What You Want Here" //make just nil 
             myCell.imagePost.image = UIImage(name: "placeholder.png") //Some Placeholder image when there is no data
        }
        return myCell
    }
```